# NSOutlineView drag and drop: how to prevent parent being dropped on one of its children

Tags: cocoa, core-data, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview

I'm setting up drag and drop for my NSOutlineView and I want to prevent parents being dropped on one of their children. The parent and children are all of the Group entity. I understand I need to do this in the outlineView:validatedrop method. I think I need to create an NSFetchRequest with the NSPredictate to get all the children of the parent, but I don't know what the predicate should be.

Edit: it should be recursively, so it should also get the children of children, if any.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSDragOperation)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)ov validateDrop:
(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedItem:(id)item proposedChildIndex:(NSInteger)childIndex;
```

In this above method, you can manage the drag item can or can't accept. Please, return `NSDragOperationNone`, means prevent drop.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Instead of digging into the core data objects, I just look at the NSTreeNodes instead, following Apple's [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AbstractTree/Introduction/Intro.html).

Bindings take care of updating the underlying core data model.  Once again, if it looks too complicated, it's probably not the correct approach.